# Can adjective and verb be used together in the given phrase?

Tags: grammar

> Hand made goods are sophisticated and pleasing to their customers.

I was told that pleasing cannot be used in the context and is grammatically wrong.

Can anyone explain.

Comment: Did they tell you why it could not be used in this context?

Comment: Her explanation was like that: "Hand made" and "sophisticated" are adjectives but you cannot use pleasing instead use pleases. Honestly, I didn't understood that's why i'm here.

Comment: I suppose an object (goods) doesn't really have customers itself. They are sold to customers by the shop selling them. If you switched that out for consumers that might work.

Comment: What I was trying to say is, hand made goods are sophisticated and due to this nature their buyers find them pleasing. Can you paraphrase that ?

Comment: See if the instructor has a problem with: *Hand made goods are sophisticated, and they are pleasing to their customers.* Then ask about: *Hand made goods are sophisticated, and are pleasing to their customers.*

Comment: In this sentence, the only verb is *are*. Both *sophisticated* and [*pleasing*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasing) are adjectives. Just follow the dictionary link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, the only verb is "are". Both "sophisticated" and "pleasing" are adjectives.  Therefore, you aren't incorrectly mixing up adjectives and verbs.  The sentence is fine.

Here is a [dictionary entry for "pleasing"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleasing).

> Adjective
>   pleasing (comparative more pleasing, superlative most pleasing)
>   Agreeable; giving pleasure, cheer, enjoyment or gratification.